# Cartthrob saving price as base64 in purchased items channel

Tags: cartthrob

I *think* this may be a bug, but it's not a biggy.

I have a product channel with a price by member group field.
My orders get saved to Orders and Purchased items channels, both based on standard setup iirc.
My purchased items channel includes a Price field {purchased_price} type: CartThrob Price - Simple.

If someone places an order where the price is ZERO (registered members can book event places for free), then the purchased item stores the price as e.g. `YToyOntpOjA7YToyOntzOjEyOiJtZW1iZXJfZ3JvdXAiO3M6MToiNSI7czo1OiJwcmljZSI7czoxOiIwIjt9aToxO2E6Mjp7czoxMjoibWVtYmVyX2dyb3VwIjtzOjA6IiI7czo1OiJwcmljZSI7czoxOiI1Ijt9fQ==` not £0 as expected.

[image: YToyOntpOjA7YToyOntzOjEyOiJtZW1iZXJfZ3JvdXAiO3M6MToiNSI7czo1OiJwcmljZSI7czoxOiIwIjt9aToxO2E6Mjp7czoxMjoibWVtYmVyX2dyb3VwIjtzOjA6IiI7czo1OiJwcmljZSI7czoxOiI1Ijt9fQ==]

I realised that is a base64 encoding of something, that turns out to be e.g `a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:12:"member_group";s:1:"5";s:5:"price";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:2:{s:12:"member_group";s:0:"";s:5:"price";s:1:"5";}}` - which appears to be the array of member prices available.

The orders channel correctly stores the total order price as £0.00, and the {order_items} price is also 0, this only affects the purchased items channel.
If an order is placed for any price > 0, then it stores the selected member price as expected. So i suspect 0 is being taken for null somewhere?

`{exp:cartthrob:debug_info}` shows price as **0 (uses customer price)** all the way thru the process.

Like I say, it's not critical for me, as the one place I am using a report of individual items, I can use the hilarious grep workaround `{if purchased_price ~ "/..................../"}£0{if:else}{purchased_price}{/if}` (assume long strings are not for billion pound orders!)
but it would be good to know whether it's a real thing or not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of CT and EE is this?

Comment: ee 2.10.1, cartthrob 2.70

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with Vector; we make CartThrob)

Thanks for reporting this! I've logged it in our bug tracker and, if it's a global issue, we'll evaluate it for fix in the next CT3 release!